# Adding a variable from a function into database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently trying to assign a random 'room key' if you like to a user when they sign up, I already have the login and signup form made and working however I am unsure as to how to enter the variable that I am running through the function into the table along with the users detail. I have this piece of code which creates a random string, I'm just struggling to know where to put this piece of code and how to get it to insert into the table.

```
function getName($n){
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1);
        $randomString .= $characters[$index];
    }

    return $randomString;
}
echo $randomString;
```

Thank you for any help in advanced :)

Comment: You need to call the function and store the value in a variable: `$theString = getName(16);` (the number 16 is just an example since the function requires an argument). That's what `return $randomString;` does, returns the value in that variable. Now you can do what ever you want with `$theString`. The variable `$randomString` only exists inside the scope of the function and can't be accessed from the outside directly.

Comment: I would recommend that you read the manual about [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), [returning values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) and [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). These are some of the basic concepts that you need to learn, or you will struggle going forward.

Comment: do I need to put that within my server code (which connects me to my database and allows signup and login to occur) or in the signup page code and then call for it in the server code